# htaccess mask url and route to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am attempting to have a Wordpress installation inside a subdirectory called /wp off of the root of the site, and have .com/blog/post-name-here or .com/how-to/post-name-here route into that /wp directory and have WP build the page, etc.

Here is what I would like to happen:

http://www.example.com/blog/post-name-here secretly routes to the /wp directory and boots up WP and let's it do it's thing

http://www.example.com/how-to/post-name-here secretly routes to the /wp directory and boots up WP and let's it do it's thing

All other requests can go on their merry way.

And here is what I have so far in .htaccess (which is not working)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect site users to wp/ folder for /blog or /how-to requests
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This takes .com/blog/ to .com/wp/, which is not what I want.

Please let me know if you need any further information.  Htaccess is not my strong suite and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only need to change `http://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp/$1` to
 `http://%{SERVER_NAME}/how-to/$1`